# How to get the information from 'first throw call stack' in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I got a crash from my client，As shown below
[image]

How can I figure out where the problem is from this picture？
How to get information from this? 
What does '+1036' mean behind '[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]'?

Comment: some where in your app `nil` is getting store in `dictionary` that is not allowed I mean its invalid data to store in dict.

Comment: you can add an excepiton breakpoint to see where it is

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add an `All exception break point` in X-Code. 
Please follow the steps below.

[image]

Now run your code. This will hit your error point on code. And this because, you are trying to set a null key on a dictionary. After you add the all exception break point you can find the exact line.

For more info please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)

Comment: You sir, can call yourself the hero of the day, never knew about this feature. Thank you so much!

Comment: I second that. Hero of my day too.